# onresize reloading issues

Tags: html, css

I put this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Condensed' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>  
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Abbey Test</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>
<script src="js/libs/modernizr-2.5.3.min.js"></script>

<![if !IE]> <body onresize="document.location=window.location";> <![endif]>
<!--[if IE]> <body onresize="window.location.reload()"> <![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
var config = {
  kitId: 'dlv2pds',
  scriptTimeout: 3000
};
var h=document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];h.className+=" wf-loading";var t=setTimeout(function(){h.className=h.className.replace(/(\s|^)wf-loading(\s|$)/g," ");h.className+=" wf-inactive"},config.scriptTimeout);var tk=document.createElement("script"),d=false;tk.src='//use.typekit.net/'+config.kitId+'.js';tk.type="text/javascript";tk.async="true";tk.onload=tk.onreadystatechange=function(){var a=this.readyState;if(d||a&&a!="complete"&&a!="loaded")return;d=true;clearTimeout(t);try{Typekit.load(config)}catch(b){}};var s=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(tk,s)
})();
</script>


<body onload="draw();">
```

in an HTML5 page I am making to compensate for a chrome window resizing problem I am having.  This causes IE to keep reloading. I am trying to make this page responsive but I am running into the nitty gritty.

Thanks

Comment: On your actual page did you close the HEAD element as required before your conditional statements?

Comment: I just updated the code above.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you should leave the first `<body ..>` without any conditionals as they are not interpreted in browsers `!=` IE

**Edit**

After rethinking your problem (IE would display two `<body>` tags :/) you should try this approach

```
<!--[if IE]>    <body onresize="window.location.reload()"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--> <body onresize="document.location=window.location";> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Taken from html5boilerplate ;)

**EDIT** *After @Schnaars comment*

Your site is reloading because your are calling `window.location.reload()` [ [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location#Methods) ] everytime you resize a window (the `resize` event is called every time your page loads). You put it into IE conditional and that's why it keeps reloading. 
You propably want to redraw "something" at page resize, just call `onresize="draw()"` like `<body onload="draw()" onresize="draw()">`.

*Sidenote:* using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) or similar library would make event handling and other things easier ;)

Comment: Other browsers would interpret the `<!--[if !IE]><!-->` conditional as simple HTML comment so they display the part between `<!-->` and `<!--<`.

Comment: I think you are probably right but I replaced the code that I had and the browser still keeps reloading.

Comment: You have three (!) `<body>` tags in your code (two in codintionals and one with `onload=""`, also move your scripts into `<head>` or `<body>` not between.